# http accept and content-type headers confusion

Tags: http, http-headers, webserver

This is an example of HTTP request message transmitted to the web server. Inside headers there is an Accept header. I am confused about the meaning of it and how it is created. I thought it solely specifies my browsers capabilities to handle files. But that doesn't explain why does it differ when I visit amazon.com or joes-hardware.

<strike>There is also Content-Type header, which is a MIME for a file it requested. Same question. How does my browser know what is the type of file it requested? Is it based on the URI extension I requested or is this a generic header?</strike> This header seems to only be send in response headers. My mistake.

```
GET /tools.html HTTP/1.0
User-agent: Mozilla/4.75 [en] (Win98; U) Host: www.joes-hardware.com
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg 
Accept-language: en
```

Comment: Where did you get that example? While `GET` *can* have a body, it is most unusual and to my knowledge no browser does that. I am also fairly certain you're not running Windows 98.

Comment: Its from a book I am reading. it was published in 2002. And yes, I am indeed not running Windows 98 :D

Comment: What I have posted are headers and not body of a request. Open any developer tools and check for a outgoing request and you will see a similar image with cookies and things like that sending along side.

Comment: Would that book by any chance be "HTTP: The Definite Guide" by David Gourley et al.? btw: The `Content-Type` header **can** appear among request headers. But it would only make sense if there is a request body.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you! Could you please take a look at Accept headers and why do they change depending on different browsing URLs?

Comment: And you are correct about the book! Great stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: `Accept`and `Accept-Language` are headers defined in [RFC 7231, section 5.3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2) and [section 5.3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.5), respectively. Together with `Accept-*` headers, they enable content negotiation through the client. There is an excellent article regarding content engotiation on the [Mozilla Development Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation). (On a side-note: The MDN is an excellent starting point for research. A lot of the articles are outdated, but the concepts are still largely valid)

The content of the `Accept-Language` is largely controlled by the language settings of a client's UI. Mozilla's Firefox (and - IIRC - Opera and Safari) allows to tweak these through its settings while MSIE seems to deduct them from the keyboard layouts installed in the system. There is nothing in the type of requested media that should influence this header.

The content of the `Accept` header on the other hand is very much depending on the context in which a resource is being requested. E.g. if you request a resource through your browser's address bar, the `Accept` header will pretty much read like "give me anything I can digest." If the browser is requesting a resource through an `<img/>`-tag, the header is going to differ in that the browser is trying to get a presentation of the requested resource that is fit for being displayed inside that tag. Same for `<video/>`, `<audio/>`, and `<script/>`.

Beyond that, I am not aware of any mechanisms effecting the `Accept` header. `<a/>`-tags have - unknownst to most - a [`type`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#adef-type-A) attribute which is carrying a MIME mediatype. This is, however, a fallback mechanism and should not alter `Accept` in any way.

As for your example, I took the liberty of requesting both sites and copying the relevant request headers:

### amazon.com

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.amazon.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

### joes-hardware.com

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.joes-hardware.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

The headers are no different when requesting `/tools.html` in the last example.